# CUURENT_DATE() in native query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql, eclipse-jee

**HI! family, I had something before, now I am using current date, in my native query, but I have nothing after execution**

```
@Query(value="select * from operation where  date_operation  = CURRENT_DATE()", nativeQuery =true)
public Page<Operation> listByPageAndByMC(Pageable page);
```

**after run,  in  hibernate journalise a have this :**
Hibernate: select * from operation where  date_operation  = CURRENT_DATE() limit ?, ?
Hibernate: select count(*) from operation where  date_operation  = CURRENT_DATE()

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="operations")
public String peration(Model model) {
    
    Page<Operation> ops = operationDao.listPageOp(1, 10);

    model.addAttribute("operation", ops);
```

return "oper/operationday";
}

[image]

Comment: do have record in your database for current date ?

Comment: yes, i have many data  in my database